# How to locate apk file using bitbucket-pipelines?

Tags: android, continuous-integration, bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using BitBucket-pipelines for Android CI. I'm trying to export the artifact (generated apk) to the downloads section of the project.

My **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** is as follows, but it can't locate the apk file

```
image: openjdk:8

pipelines:
default:
- step:
    caches:
      - gradle
      - android-sdk

    script:
      # Download and unzip android sdk
      - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
      - unzip -o -qq android-sdk.zip -d android-sdk

      # Define Android Home and add PATHs
      - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/android-sdk"
      - export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"

      # Download packages.
      - yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools"
      - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
      - yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"
      - yes | sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
      - yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
      - yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;instantapps"
      - yes | sdkmanager --licenses

      # Build apk
      - chmod a+x ./gradlew
      - ./gradlew assembleDebug

      # Saving artifact
      - curl -X POST "https://${BB_AUTH_STRING}@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"**/*.apk"


definitions:
  caches:
     android-sdk: android-sdk
```

The issue is in

```
- curl -X POST "https://${BB_AUTH_STRING}@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"**/*.apk"
```

I've also tried the following instead of `**/*.apk`

```
./app/build/outputs/apk/*.apk
```

But so far, nothing can locate the apk.

Has anyone faced this issue before? I'm just getting into CI with Android and would be grateful if someone could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding an artifacts tag after the build step. Then to publish the apk file I had to point to the specific file (path respective to the parent folder).

My **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** file is as follows now.

```
image: openjdk:8

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
      caches:
        - gradle
        - android-sdk

      script:
        # Download and unzip android sdk
        - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-3859397.zip
        - unzip -o -qq android-sdk.zip -d android-sdk

        # Define Android Home and add PATHs
        - export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/android-sdk"
        - export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"

        # Download packages.
        - yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools"
        - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
        - yes | sdkmanager "build-tools;27.0.3"
        - yes | sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"
        - yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;m2repository"
        - yes | sdkmanager "extras;google;instantapps"
        - yes | sdkmanager --licenses

        # Build apk
        - chmod a+x ./gradlew
        - ./gradlew assembleDebug

      artifacts:
        - app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk

  - step:
     script:
        # Saving artifact
        - curl -X POST "https://${BB_AUTH_STRING}@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"


definitions:
    caches:
        android-sdk: android-sdk
```

Comment: When I set the config file in my project I get an error: 
"Configuration error: There is an error in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [pipelines > default > 0]. To be precise: Step is empty, null, or missing."

Comment: It can happen because of wrong spaces. could you share the config file as Gist?

Comment: I've refactored the config file (only changed spaces). Maybe it will be useful for someone - https://gist.github.com/albka1986/f1c6bdca1823e8d7a894f1c47bc3819a

Comment: @PonomarenkoOleh yes this may occur due to indentation. Thank you for posting the Gist, glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this command to export the latest apk

```
LATEST_APK=$(ls -lrt ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/*.apk | tail -1 | awk -F" " '{ print $9 }')
```

and then the curl post command to upload it to downloads section of Bitbucket

```
curl -s -u "${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}:${BB_AUTH_STRING}" -X POST "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" -F files=@"${LATEST_APK}" --verbose
```